# TypeError: 'Question' object is not iterable in test case assertion

Tags: python, django

I am testing whether the context variable contains a string

```
def test_past_question(self):
    past_question = create_question(question_text='past question',days=-30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',args=(past_question.id,)))    
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['question'],'<Question: past question>')
```

But it throws the following error:

> (mysite) sugumar@mysitedotcom:~/python/django/mysite$ python
>   manage.py test polls Creating test database for alias 'default'...
>   System check identified no issues (0 silenced). .E........
>   ====================================================================== ERROR: test_past_question (polls.tests.QuestionDetailViewTests)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sugumar/python/django/mysite/polls/tests.py", line 73, in
>   test_past_question
>       self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['question'],'')   File
>   "/home/sugumar/.local/share/virtualenvs/mysite-VWHaFuat/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py",
>   line 946, in assertQuerysetEqual
>       items = map(transform, qs) TypeError: 'Question' object is not iterable
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 10 tests in 0.069s
>
> FAILED (errors=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

In the command line:

```
>>> from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
>>> setup_test_environment()
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> client = Client()
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> response = client.get(reverse('polls:detail',args=(1,)))
>>> response.context
[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0xb74425ec>, 'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0xb69feecc>, 'user': <SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0xb7440bfc>>, 'csrf_token': <SimpleLazyObject: 'FrAJ52rWG57SSbSE9y4V2tammjvQqjBUyl2tK6aEzj8ZfENSyFl7Fy05bnQh3XyQ'>, 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/polls/1/'>, 'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30, 'ERROR': 40}}, {}, {'object': <Question: What's Up?>, 'question': <Question: What's Up?>, 'view': <polls.views.DetailView object at 0xb6a2fd4c>}]
>>> response.context['question']
<Question: What's Up?>
>>> exit
```

See that in the command it showed  so i tried

```
 self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['question'],'<Question: past question>')
```

Comment: Based on the *name*, `response.context['question']` is *not* a `QuerySet`, but a single `Question` object, furthermore it is likely not a string either.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem So how do I test it sir?

Comment: response.context? Or .content instead? Also assertQuerysetEqual checks a queryset, not one value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically if the variable name is singular (`'question'` is singluar), that means this is likely *not* a `QuerySet` (which is more or less a collection), but a single `Question` object.

Furthermore there is a difference between an object (like a `Question` object), and its textual representation (like `'<Question ...>'`). The two are *not* the same.

So you should check the equality with the `past_question`, like:

```
def test_past_question(self):
    past_question = create_question(question_text='past question',days=-30)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',args=(past_question.id,)))    
    self.assertEqual(response.context['question'], past_question)
```

Comment: How to become a programmer like you?

Comment: It is an opinionated answer, to advise on the best path to programming excellence (in such a case, a chatroom may be better to converse on this topic than the informational wiki pages of SO). There are infinite answers. But nonetheless, a tip from myself to you, on how to learn thoroughly and how to craft expertise, is to read the documentation on subjects from top to bottom. It is dense, but the reward is sweet.